# Looking for an application that saves clipboard history

Tags: software-recommendation

I am looking for an application that saves all CTRL C history. Is there such a thing for Ubuntu, or Linux in general?

I remember seeing on of these, but I don't quite remember the details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
apt-cache search "clipboard manager"
```

Yields the following

```
clipit - lightweight GTK+ clipboard manager
glipper - Clipboard manager for GNOME
parcellite - lightweight GTK+ clipboard manager
klipper - clipboard manager
```

The last one is for KDE

Comment: From my experience Parcellite is probably the easiest an most effective to use.

Comment: I find clipit more suitable. Glipper likes to eat your memory, and parcellite is not even shown on Unity on my desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Parcellite version 1.1.4 supports unity. The ppa is here https://launchpad.net/~rickyrockrat/+archive/parcellite-appindicator and the latest code is here http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/

There are two builds of parcellite - one with the appindicator dependency and one without.
The ppa WITHOUT unity support is https://launchpad.net/~rickyrockrat/+archive/parcellite

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Keepboard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepboard/). It is written in Java and thus works on most distros.