# What utility is like Ten Clips, providing an enumerated clipboard?

Tags: software-recommendation, clipboard

A very useful (Windows) utility I use is TenClips - http://www.paludour.net/TenClips.html

It allows you to create enumerated clipboards/emacs-like buffers easily using `ctrl` + `f1`, `ctrl` + `f2`, `ctrl` + `f3`, etc., copy to the clipboard in the first buffer, switch to the second buffer, copy without loosing our first buffer, switch back to the first buffer and paste, switch to the second buffer and paste and so forth.

Does something like this exist for Ubuntu? The closest post I could find was [Looking for an application that saves clipboard history](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63447/looking-for-an-application-that-saves-clipboard-history) which recommended Parcellite (http://parcellite.sourceforge.net/?page_id=2) - which keeps the history - but this is not quite what I'm after. If not I might make this a pet project :D

Answer (score 1):

Try Clipit, it's installable in the software center.  Clipit was forked from the Parcellite clipboard manager and has more features and bugfixes but you might like Parcellite over Clipit.

The really big advantage of a clipboard manager under Linux is that it will maintain the clipboard even after you close the application you did the cut from.  Losing the clipboard when you close an application is one of those little bugbears in Linux that you either learn to live with, or get around by using one of these clipboard managers.

To re-use the clipboard history with enumeration open the preferences and turn "Automatically paste selected item" and "Show indexes in History" on.  You would then use the hotkeys for history, and then press the number of the item you want to paste.  The hotkey for history is programmable, however you might want to leave it as it is for the moment: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>

While this does not let you store items under a specific number, you do get a visible list of the items which is sortable if you want.  The programmable actions would seem to be another way of doing things, however there's not much documentation on this feature at the moment.  I believe the history hotkey and automatic paste feature should give you most of the functionality you need.  Chris

Comment: Thank you Chris. I had a look at Clipit - it stores the history, but I couldn't figure out how to recall it using enumeration as described above (I can't stress how useful this feature is). In other words, I want to copy with `ctrl` + `f1` (or something similar), switch to the second+ buffer and copy (`ctrl` + `f2`, `ctrl` + `f3`, etc.), but know that I can use `ctrl` + `f1` to get back to my original clipboard WITHOUT the need to go through clipboard history OR having to remember what order I copied it in.

Comment: I've added information into the answer to do most of what you want with the history hotkey and numeric.  It's not quite what you wanted, but it should do what you need.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I saw that yesterday but it's not quite what I need. The problem is that I'm running some GUI tests with data from a spreadsheet, and I don't have a test layer (so having to go through the clip-board values every time is pretty annoying).

Comment: Parcellite has the option to edit some item in history, does ClipIt can do this (I could not find a way to achieve this)?

Comment: Just coming back to this after many months, I've realised that if you use [ctrl]+[alt]+[h] and then hit the number corresponding to the listed item, it makes this the current selection on the clipboard. This is close enough to what I wanted - thank you.